# Javascript Module Import and Export not Working (Importing binding name is not found.)

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I've scoured SO and the Web for answers, but have found nothing so far that has helped.  When navigating to my test site (see below), I'm getting this error: `Importing binding name 'Person' is not found.`

From index.html:

```
<script type="module" src="js/person.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

From script.js:

```
import {Person} from '/js/person.js';
```

From person.js:

```
export class Person {
  constructor(
    firstName, lastName, email
  ){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
  }

  setFirstName(firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  setLastName(lastName){
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  setEmail(email){
    this.email = email;
  }
```

}

All the documentation I've found appears to indicate that I'm doing this correctly, and yet I get the error.  Any ideas, anyone?

***UPDATE***
Everything works fine under Windows, but not using MacOS 12 in Safari, Firefox, or Chrome.  Why?

Comment: `from '/js/person.js';` -> `from 'js/person.js';` probably. You're importing from different paths. And I don't think you need to add person.js on the page itself, script.js referencing it should be enough.

Comment: @VLAZ that doesn't work-- it generates this error: `TypeError: Module specifier, 'js/person.js' does not start with "/", "./", or "../".`

Comment: Oh, right - they'd be in the same folder. Then `from './person.js'`

Comment: @VLAZ-- tried that as well, got the same `SyntaxError: Importing binding name 'Person' is not found.` error.

Comment: Weird - where *are* your files located in relation to each other?

Comment: I have index.html at the top level, then directories for 'js', 'img', 'css', etc. In 'js', I have 'script.js' and 'person.js'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved; I was using the 'Live Server' plugin in VS Code on MacOS to serve the site which apparently caused the problem (although under Windows, it works just fine).  When serving it with Apache on MacOS, it works.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and updating your question.

Answer (score 1):

A cause of this error message (though not in OP's case) is, when importing from a module with a `default` export, using

```
import {defaultName, otherName} from ...
```

instead of

```
import defaultName, {otherName} form ...
```